# How to sort multiple files? Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sorting

Usually i can do this to sort a textfile:

```
cat infile.txt | sort > outfile.out
mv outfile.out > infile.txt
```

I can also do it in a loop:

```
for inp in ./*; do
    fname=${inp##*/}
    cat "$inp" | sort  > ./"$fname".out
done
```

Other than writing a loop, is there a one liner to do the above for all files in the terminal?

Comment: Why is UUOC better than avoiding a loop?  cats are loopy.

Comment: How is this question  "off topic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `GNU sort` you can do:

```
$ sort file -o file
```

You could use `xargs` instead of looping like:

```
$ ls | xargs -i% -n1 sort % -o %
```

If you don't have the `-o` option:

```
$ sort file > tmp && mv tmp file 

$ ls | xargs -i% -n1 sort % > tmp && mv tmp %
```

Answer (score 4):

This strikes me as an absurd exercise since there's nothing wrong with a loop, but you can do:

```
ls | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'sort $1 > $1.tmp; mv $1.tmp $1' sh
```

Comment: absurdity runs in the programmer's / sys admin's blood.